# Select and modify a slice in pandas dataframe by integer index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[10,20],[10,2],[1,40]],columns = ['a','b'])
    a   b
0   1   2
1   10  20
2   10  2
3   1   40
```

I want to select the `b` column where `a == 1`, the following is a classic selecting:

```
df[df.a == 1].b
    a   b
0   1   2
3   1   40
```

Then I want to select the ith row of this subdataframe, which isn't the row with index i. There again are several ways, like the following:

```
df[df.a == 1].b.iloc[[1]]
Output: 
3    40
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

So far so good. The problem is when I try to modify the value I got there, indeed this selection method yields a copy of the slice of the dataframe, not the object itself. Therefore I can't modify it inplace.

```
test[test.a == 1].b.iloc[[1]] = 3
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

I don't know in which part the 'copy' problem lies, since the two following yield the same problem:

```
test.iloc[[3]].b = 3
test[test.a == 1].b = 3
```

So my question is this one: how can I change a value by both a mask selection (conditionally on the `a` column value) and a row selection (by the rank of the row in the subdataframe, not its index value)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `loc` with the boolean mask and directly pass the index up:

```
In[178]:
df.loc[df.loc[df['a'] == 1,'b'].index[1], 'b'] = 3
df

Out[178]: 
    a   b
0   1   2
1  10  20
2  10   2
3   1   3
```

So here we mask the df using `df['a'] == 1`, this returns a boolean array and we mask the df and select just column `'b'`:

```
In[179]:
df.loc[df['a'] == 1,'b']

Out[179]: 
0    2
3    40
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

then just subscript the index directly:

```
In[180]:
df.loc[df['a'] == 1,'b'].index[1]

Out[180]: 3
```

We can then pass this index label back up to the top-level `loc`.

This `test[test.a == 1].b.iloc[[1]] = 3` is [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) which is why the warning is raised.

Comment: The thing to take away from this is to not chain the `loc`, `iloc` calls, you should composite the mask or if you can calculate the index label directly then you can just pass this to `loc`